# Passive View (MVP design pattern) with multiple Views

Tags: vb.net, mvp

Coming up to speed on the MVP design pattern and I have a gap in my
understanding. The consensus seems to be to design a 1:1 relationship between
Presenter and View. This makes sense -- but how would this work when state must be passed from one view to the next.

For example, imagine the following two View application;

```
1) Login Form, 
2) Data Entry Form.
```

Assume the `Data Entry Form` requires the credentials entered into the `Login Form` View.

Does the application require another layer above the MVP that orchestrates the Views? A layer that would handle showing the next (or previous) View? And how should the separate Views share data?  Should the the `Data Entry Form` Presenter have access to the `Login Form` Model?

Or does one Presenter create the next P/V in sequence. Meaning, after a user
successfully logs in, does `Login Form` Presenter create the `Data Entry Form` View and pass in the credentials?

My question is fundamentally the same one raise by [Multi-page app using passive-view MVP with multiple presenters - what is the most appropriate way to handle page changes?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/316233/multi-page-app-using-passive-view-mvp-with-multiple-presenters-what-is-the-mos) but that question is unanswered.

If it matters, the project is a WinForm written in VB.Net.

Comment: Have a look at the structure of this WinForms MVP app.  Its written using C#, but the differences between VB.NET and C# are pretty much irrelevant for this sort of thing:  http://markheath.net/post/model-view-presenter-winforms

Comment: I agree that C# & vb.net are not relevant to the discussion...but...I'm not a C# developer. I glanced at the code but there's enough going on that I can't see the answer to my overarching question -- which is how do you communicate state in an MVP design pattern.  I'm leaning towards a service layer above the MVP pattern that manages the whole process. But I was trying to see how others solved this problem.

Comment: In that example, the communication between various `Presenter` classes happens via the `EventAggregator`.     the EventAggregator pattern is equivalent to a *message broker* which passes state/information between presenters using various POCO 'message' classes.   Each presenter can Publish or Subscribe to different message POCO types which its interested in.      You could achieve exactly the same thing with a Single-instance service class instead of EventAggregator though.

Comment: Thanks Ben. If you post this as Answer, I'll mark it accepted.